# Decompress gzip stream for silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, json, gzip

I am trying to decompress a json gzipped stream in silverlight and serialize the stream into an object.  I have the serialization down with an uncompressed stream but when receiving the same stream compressed it doesn't work. I know that there is a GZipStream for c# but it isn't supported by silverlight.  Does anyone know of a good library? I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ShapZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) now has a silverlight library so you can use GZipStream in silverlight.

Stream stream = new GZipInputStream(response.GetResponseStream());

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but the documentation says that [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) can do that.